# 3D Finite Difference Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, finite-differences

I have been working with a finite difference code for the case in which my problem is axysimmetric.  This means that all the code I have so far is for 2D  In this case the coefficient matrix isn't hard to set up. For example, a coefficient matrix would be of the form:

$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        -4 & 1 &  0 & 0 & 1 \\
        1 & -4 & 1 &  0 & 0 & 1 \\
        0 & 1 & -4 & 1 &  0 & 0 & 1 \\
        0 & 0 & 1 & -4 & 1 & 0  & 0 & 1 \\
        1  & 0 & 0 &1 & -4 & 1 & 0 &  0 & 1 \\
           & 1  & 0 & 0 &1 & -4 & 1 & 0 &  0 & 1  \\
           && 1 & 0 & 0 &1 & -4 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1  \\
        &&& \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

Here the $1$'s next to  the $-4$'s are due to finite difference equations in the $x$ direction (for example) and the ones far from it are due to the equations in the $y$ direction.

Now I have to extend the code to consider 3D cases, but I'm not sure how you would build a matrix like the above for 3D.  I image you end up adding two additional diagonals of $1$'s but I'm not sure exactly where.

Thanks for the help.

(Note: The $-4$'s and $1$'s are just for the example, my specific problem has variable coefficients, but this makes no difference for the structure of the matrix.)

Comment: does not your coefficient matrix depend on how you have labelled, you number the grid points row-wise or colum-wise and the finite differencing your pde. i am not sure how you even got your string of ones above the super diagonal only two places farther. i would have guessed that it to the breadth of the domain.

Comment: There is a small error in the matrices, that is all the matrices are diagonal 1. With $-k, -k, \cdots, -k$ on the diagonal of the matrix $D_k$. 2. With the diagonal $D_k, D_k, \cdots, D_k$ for the matrix $E_k$. 3. with the diagonal $E_k, E_k, \cdots, E_k$ for the matrix $F_k$. The $1$'s and the identity matrices will be on the upper and lower sub-diagonals.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $D_k \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ with 
\begin{align}
D_k = \begin{pmatrix}
-k & 1 & 0 & 0& ... & 0\\
1 & -k & 1 & 0& ... &0 \\
& \ddots &\ddots&\ddots&\\
0 & 0& 0& 1 & -k&1
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
Then we know, that the $1D$ finite difference matrix is given by $D_2$. Let $I$ be the $n\times n$ identity matrix. For the $2D$ case we have the matrix $E_k\in \mathbb{R}^{n^2 \times n^2}$ defined as
\begin{align}
E_k=\begin{pmatrix}
D_k & I & 0 & 0&... & 0 \\
I & D_k & I& 0&...&0\\
& \ddots &\ddots&\ddots&\\
0 & 0&0&I &D_k & I
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
Then the $2D$ finite difference is given by $E_4$. Now let $J$ be the $n^2 \times n^2$ identity matrix. For the $3D$ case we have the matrix $F_k\in \mathbb{R}^{n^3 \times n^3}$ defined as
\begin{align}
F_k=\begin{pmatrix}
E_k & J & 0 & 0&... & 0 \\
J & E_k & J& 0&...&0\\
& \ddots &\ddots&\ddots&\\
0 & 0&0&J &E_k & J
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
And obviously, the $3D$ finite difference matrix is given by $F_6$

Comment: Thanks, this was what I needed.

Comment: Of course, one would try to avoid to create the matrix in its explicit form, since only 6 of the $n^3$ elements per row are nonzero.

Comment: Yes, of course :) I just wanted to be sure where the extra diagonals go.